# Use Multiple Type in Generic T C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this interface base repo with genric type T:

```
public interface IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    void Add(T obj);
}
```

and this interfaces heritance from the IRepositoryBase

```
public interface IClass1Repository : IRepositoryBase<Class1>
{
}
public interface IClass2Repository : IRepositoryBase<Class2>
{
}
```

and this the class implementation of  IRepositoryBase

```
public class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    public RepositoryBase(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public void Add(T obj)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Add(obj);
    }
}
```

and this the implementaion of class1 & class2

```
public class class1Repository : RepositoryBase<Students>, IClasse1Repository
{
    public class1Repository (Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class class2Repository : RepositoryBase<Students>, IClasse2Repository
{
    public class2Repository (Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

& in this methode i need to return one of Repo

```
private IRepositoryBase<> GetRepository(string a)
{
    var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
    switch (a)
    {

        case "class1":
            return scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IClass1Repository>();
        case "class2":
            return  scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IClass2Repository>();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But inside the brackets in `IRepositoryBase` it takes one type of class1 or class2 so in my case I need to return by params a.

How to use union or something else to set the multiple types in barckets and choose the return by conditon in params a?

Comment: How would this work? You cannot use an open generic type as the return type of a method

Comment: @JonasHøgh i return the service with IClass1Repository or IClass2Repository and IClass1Repository  take like a type class1 and IClass2Repository class2

Comment: There are many naming errors in your examples. Fixing these through psychological debugging™️, what you apparently need is a `IRepositoryBase<T> GetRepository<T>()` class. You won't get around determining the type of entities the repository manages since callers of that method will require to know that too.

Comment: There are multiple reasons why you shouldn't do this. First off, you are using a service locator anti-pattern. Second, your repository base should have no knowledge of the inheriting types. And third, if you have to have explicit knowledge of each potential implementing type, there's no point to a generic repository in the first place. If your generic repository abstraction is not solving a specific problem, I would highly recommend abandoning it. And I don't see any problem it solves here.

Comment: @Stack `IClasse1/2Repository` should be `IClass1/2Repository`, you meant `string` and not `sting` in the `GetRepository` parameter, and there is no parameter `tableName` which supposedly should be `a` or `a` should be `tableName`.